# Add gradient fill in svg as background url css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, svg

I have a circle svg called in css as background url.And now I wanted to add gradient color on it.  I tried to add gradient codes but unfortunately its not really working but when I removed the gradiant codes it works but I need the gradient color :(.

What I done so far is :

```
 .a {
    background: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 500 500' preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin meet'> <linearGradient x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='100%' id='gradient'><stop stop-color='#c86dd7' offset='0'/><stop stop-color='#3023ae' offset='100%'/></linearGradient><circle fill='url(#gradient)' cx='250' cy='250' r='240'/></svg>");
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgjhms17/2/

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you need to encode your # character

Comment: I already did. But its not working. What I want is gradient color not just hex.

Comment: you did not, you have 3 # in your code

Comment: oh sorry I converted it. and its now working,. Thank you

Comment: This helped me. Thanks @SanvAriana for making the fiddle.